# Why are the hypergeometric functions called "hypergeometric"?

Tags: terminology, special-functions

I was wondering where the term "hypergeometric" for the hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a, b; c; z)$ comes from. Wikipedia says that the term was coined by J. Wallis, but I couldn't find any (mathematical) reason why these functions are anything like hyper-geometric.

Does anyone know where this comes from?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/295258/442

Comment: In Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik's *Concrete Mathematics* they have a comment when introducing the hypergeometric series on the etymology of the name in relation to the geometric series. I do not have the book in front of me right now. Maybe someone else can check.

Comment: On Page 206 (Second Edition) they write: "... is called hypergeometric series because it includes the geometric series as a very special case."

Answer (score 9):

This is the reason I believe: a *geometric* sequence is defined as a sequence where the ratio of two consecutive numbers is a constant
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = x\,.
$$
You can generalize this notion by assuming the ratio to be any rational function of $n$ instead
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{P(n)}{Q(n)}\,.
$$
Any such rational function can be factorized and rewritten as
$$
\frac{P(n)}{Q(n)} = \frac{(n+a_1)\cdots(n+a_p)}{(n+b_1)\cdots(n+b_q)(n+1)}x\,.
$$
If $Q(n)$ doesn't have an $n+1$ factor we can always say, for example, $a_p=1$, so we don't lose generality. With this parametrization it's easy to check that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = {}_pF_q(a_1,\ldots, a_p;b_1,\ldots, b_q;x)\,.
$$
*Hypergeometric* then suggests that this is a generalization of the *geometric* sequence. More precisely
$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = {}_1F_0(1;;x)\,.
$$

Source: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html

Comment: No, why? Setting ap=1 cancels the denominator

Comment: OK (+1+1), I understand your intention now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The probability mass function of the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) (related to the binomial distribution and the geometric distribution) is given by a ratio of products of binomial coefficients, just like the coefficients of the MacLaurin series of a hypergeometric function. This is my bet on the reason for picking the adjective *hypergeometric* for describing the $\phantom{}_p F_q$ functions.

Comment: It would be nice to know if the downvote is due to the fact that I am wrong, or something else.

Comment: So the etymology is "geometric sequence" $\to$ "geometric distribution" $\to$ "hypergeometric distribution" $\to$ "hypergeometric function"? I found it slightly disorienting that the answer started in the middle of that chain rather than at one of the ends -- but not so disorienting that I'd downvote.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I am not sure that is the historical chain of events, but is sounds likely, doesn't it?